# Maintaining LibreOffice Draw documents in a git repository

Tags: git, scripting, draw, libreoffice

I am writing a novel and maintain my content in a markdown text format that I then convert to html using a Python script.  Since the markdown is text only, I am able to maintain it in git version control very easily.

I'm wanting to add some diagrams created in LibreOffice Draw to this.  However, it looks like this won't be trivial to make work well in git, since LibreOffice drawings save in a binary format, which is not as easy to maintain in git.

If I save a Libre Office drawing, the choices are .odg (binary) or .sxd (text based xml, but with many binary sections inserted into it) -- git treats both of these as binary files.  The two template formats, .otg and .std run into the same problem.  This could have provided a solution if I could have used a script to convert the drawings to image files and had my novel's document reference them from the generated html file.

If I paste a drawing into a LibreOffice document then save it as an html file, it saves it as encoded image data within this.  If I want to use my Python script, this won't work, since I would need the original drawings to be maintained in git version control.  Even if I maintained the html document directory, the encoded content is not directly manageable.

Can anyone else think of a way to manage drawings in git for this?  Otherwise my only options are to go ahead and commit binary odg files (in which case I must commit less often to avoid repository bloat) or use Git LFS, in which case I need to maintain all versions of the drawing files in a separate directory to be pointed to.

Comment: Did you try to convert the drawings to [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)? Since SVG is xml-based, it may be better suitable to be maintained by a version control system.

Comment: There are more text-based image formats, for example PNM, see [Image file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats).

Comment: A text based format such as SVG would solve the problem, though if SVG files are what I maintain in git, I could not use LibreOffice to edit them.  It sounds like the program Inkscape allows creation of flow charts, so that might be an option for maintaining SVG files.  It doesn't sound like LibreOffice Draw can be used to edit the files if I want to use something text based for git.